# How to get AJAX query to work on mobile device or Edge

Tags: ajax

The following works fine on Google Chrome but will not work on a mobile device or Microsoft Edge

```
 </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#ac').on('change', function() {
                var aircraft = $(this).val();
                   $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "http://app.loneeagleflyingschool.org.au/aircraft.php?aircraft=" + aircraft,
                success: function(data) {
                  $("#tacho").html(data);
                  $("#tacho").collapse('show');

                }
              });
            });
        });


    </script>
```

Comment: Any messages in the console? And you should encode your variable for use in a query string.

Comment: How is this related to java or php?

Comment: Soleved now it was the origin it was pointing to was not a https. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Soleved now it was the origin it was pointing to was not a https. Resolved by changing to a https origin